# Why is Firefox 6 ignoring my height, width, top and left settings in javascript window.open?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, web

Can anybody see what's wrong with my code?  It behaves properly in IE but firefox 6 seems to ignore any height or width settings that I pass through to the javascript window.open call.  I can't see anything obviously wrong with it but javascript isn't my first language so I may be making a noob error somewhere in this.

The purpose of this function is to open an 800x600 window centered on the screen and displayed modally in both IE and Mozilla family browsers.

```
<html>
<head>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function openWindow(pageURL,Title,w,h) 
    {
        var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
        var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
        if (window.showModalDialog) {
            window.showModalDialog(pageURL,Title,'dialogWidth:' + w     + 'px,dialogHeight:'+ h + 'px,dialogTop:'+ top + 'px,dialogLeft:' + left + ',resizable=no');
        } else {
            window.open(pageURL,Title,"toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no,     status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,modal=yes,     copyhistory=no,width=" + w + ", height=" + h + ", top=" + top + ", left=" + left)
        }
    }   

</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:openWindow('http://www.google.com','Google',800,600);">Launch</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Just to clarify a bit, the function is designed to test for the presence of ShowModalDialog (presuming that only IE supported it) and fall into the proper window.open branch in everything that supports the W3C window.open command which implements the "Modal" option.  The idea being that if ShowModalDialog was implemented then it would use that otherwise use the window.open with the "Modal" option.

Comment: `showModalDialog` is basically supported by all browsers now, so assuming that only IE will fall into that codepath is a bad assumption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Semi-colons, not commas, in showModalDialog:

```
<html>
<head>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function openWindow(pageURL,Title,w,h) 
    {
        var left = (screen.width - w) / 2;
        var top = (screen.height - h) / 2;
        var options;
        if (window.showModalDialog) {
            options = 'dialogwidth:' + w     + ';dialogheight:'+ h + ';dialogtop:'+ top + ';dialogleft:' + left + ';resizable=no';
            console.log(options);
            window.showModalDialog(pageURL, Title, options);
        } else {
            options = "toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,modal=yes, copyhistory=no, width=" + w + ", height=" + h + ", top=" + top + ", left=" + left;
            console.log("window.open options: " + options);
            window.open(pageURL, Title, options)
        }
    }   

</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:openWindow('http://www.google.com','Google',800,600);">Launch</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oddly the IE version (showmodaldialog) is working fine in IE.

Comment: Thanks Sam, Firefox 6 was falling into the ShowModalDialog branch which I wasn't expecting and indeed it was the commas rather than semi-colons that was invalidating the options I was passing in.  Good catch!  I'd never have figured that out :)

Answer (score 0):

Is `showModalDialog()` a valid member of `window`? I can't find it in the documentation.

Edit: Just did a quick Google search. `showModalDialog` is not a W3C standard and is not implemented in Firefox.

Edit: I'm wrong. Firefox caved and started supporting it.

Comment: That would be incorrect, [window.showModalDialog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.showModalDialog) is supported in Firefox 3+

Comment: Often the easiest way to check if an object or method is supported by a browser is to enter it in the console!

Comment: In this function the showModalDialog is only supposed to be executed if the browser supports it, my intention was that only IE would fall into that branch and anything Mozilla based would use the proper window.open command

Comment: Just a quick update - I hadn't thought Firefox 6 would support ShowModalDialog so it was unexpectedly following through that branch in the flow, all my attempts to figure it out had been in the other branch - sticking an alert in there showed that it was flowing into the ShowModalDialog branch and then Sam's suggestion of replacing the commas with semi-colons caused the options I was passing to ShowModalDialog to be applied and voila - height and width enabled :)