# Popup are opening in same window instead of new popup window

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, popup

I know this question has been asked too many times, and i have tried various options suggested, but i am still unable to get it working. Its working perfectly well on chrome, firefox, ie6, ie7 but somehow in ie8 and ie9 it opens in same window. I am attaching my code below for reference

```
function login(url){
    var width = 550;
    var height = 300;
    console.log(screen.width);
    console.log(screen.height);
    var left = (screen.width/2)-(width/2);
    var top = (screen.height/2)-(height/2);
    fconnect = window.open(url, "SignIn", "width=550, height=300, toolbar=0,\
                                scrollbars=0, status=0, resizable=0, \
                                top=" + top);

    fconnect.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert on the intricacies of window.open, but window opening behaviour will partly depend on user settings and whether popup blockers are installed.

The example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272383/why-is-firefox-6-ignoring-my-height-width-top-and-left-settings-in-javascript-w/7272832#7272832) might help, if you want a modal dialog.

Comment: somehow i got it working today on ie. Anyways thanks for your response. I am not sure whaich change did it .